# How do you get the index of a JSON value in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is get some stats from the NHL api for a particular date. My thinking is if I can find the index of a particular date value I could pass in the date as a variable to get that index. As an example toi will return the time on ice stat for this player for the date value that is at index 0. I first would like to get the index of a particular date then use that index to get that stat for the date that I'm looking for.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

def main():

    ID=8476923
    params = dict(stats='gameLog', season='20192020')
    url = f"https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/{ID}/stats/"
    res = requests.get(url, params=params)
    if res.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("ERROR: API request unsuccessful.")
    data = res.json()
    mylist = data["stats"][0]["splits"]

    toi = data["stats"][0]["splits"][0]["stat"]["timeOnIce"]


    print(f"{mylist}")
    print(f"{toi}")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is first bit data returned in mylist:

```
[ {
      "season" : "20192020",
      "stat" : {
        "timeOnIce" : "25:42",
        "assists" : 0,
        "goals" : 0,
        "pim" : 0,
        "shots" : 4,
        "games" : 1,
        "hits" : 1,
        "powerPlayGoals" : 0,
        "powerPlayPoints" : 0,
        "powerPlayTimeOnIce" : "03:54",
        "evenTimeOnIce" : "21:01",
        "penaltyMinutes" : "0",
        "shotPct" : 0.0,
        "gameWinningGoals" : 0,
        "overTimeGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedPoints" : 0,
        "shortHandedTimeOnIce" : "00:47",
        "blocked" : 1,
        "plusMinus" : 0,
        "points" : 0,
        "shifts" : 31
      },
      "team" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "New Jersey Devils",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1"
      },
      "opponent" : {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Boston Bruins",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/6"
      },
      "date" : "2019-12-31",
      "isHome" : true,
      "isWin" : true,
      "isOT" : false,
      "game" : {
        "gamePk" : 2019020613,
        "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020613/feed/live",
        "content" : {
          "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020613/content"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "season" : "20192020",
      "stat" : {
        "timeOnIce" : "24:59",
        "assists" : 1,
        "goals" : 0,
        "pim" : 0,
        "shots" : 2,
        "games" : 1,
        "hits" : 3,
        "powerPlayGoals" : 0,
        "powerPlayPoints" : 1,
        "powerPlayTimeOnIce" : "02:32",
        "evenTimeOnIce" : "19:37",
        "penaltyMinutes" : "0",
        "shotPct" : 0.0,
        "gameWinningGoals" : 0,
        "overTimeGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedPoints" : 0,
        "shortHandedTimeOnIce" : "02:50",
        "blocked" : 2,
        "plusMinus" : 0,
        "points" : 1,
        "shifts" : 32
      },
      "team" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "New Jersey Devils",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1"
      },
      "opponent" : {
        "id" : 9,
        "name" : "Ottawa Senators",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/9"
      },
      "date" : "2019-12-29",
      "isHome" : false,
      "isWin" : true,
      "isOT" : false,
      "game" : {
        "gamePk" : 2019020603,
        "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020603/feed/live",
        "content" : {
          "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020603/content"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "season" : "20192020",
      "stat" : {
        "timeOnIce" : "24:32",
        "assists" : 0,
        "goals" : 0,
        "pim" : 0,
        "shots" : 1,
        "games" : 1,
        "hits" : 2,
        "powerPlayGoals" : 0,
        "powerPlayPoints" : 0,
        "powerPlayTimeOnIce" : "00:04",
        "evenTimeOnIce" : "20:49",
        "penaltyMinutes" : "0",
        "shotPct" : 0.0,
        "gameWinningGoals" : 0,
        "overTimeGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedGoals" : 0,
        "shortHandedPoints" : 0,
        "shortHandedTimeOnIce" : "03:39",
        "blocked" : 0,
        "plusMinus" : -1,
        "points" : 0,
        "shifts" : 29
      },
      "team" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "New Jersey Devils",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/1"
      },
      "opponent" : {
        "id" : 10,
        "name" : "Toronto Maple Leafs",
        "link" : "/api/v1/teams/10"
      },
      "date" : "2019-12-27",
      "isHome" : true,
      "isWin" : false,
      "isOT" : true,
      "game" : {
        "gamePk" : 2019020583,
        "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020583/feed/live",
        "content" : {
          "link" : "/api/v1/game/2019020583/content"
        }
      }
    },
```

So at index 0 you can see the time on ice is 25:42 which is what in fact gets returned in `toi`. If I change the code to `toi = data["stats"][0]["splits"][1]["stat"]["timeOnIce"]`, `toi` will return 24:59. I would like to, for example, search the code first for date "2019-12-29", then pass in that index which is 1. I'm think there must be an easy way to do this, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I was trying the index(), but that didn't seem to find it.

Comment: Is there a reason a simple loop and incrementing counter variable won't do this job?

Comment: Probably. I can't seem to figure it out. I tried indices = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(mylist):
        if 'date' in elem:
            indices.append(i)   Which return all the indices of the word date, but when I put in something like 2019-12-31 it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: I failed to understand what you are trying to achive... Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to increment an integer variable?

Comment: You were right, thanks. I started the count at 0, did a while loop incrementing the count after each try. while d != data["stats"][0]["splits"][c]["date"]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.index()` function.

```
ID=8476923
params = dict(stats='gameLog', season='20192020')
url = f"https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/{ID}/stats/"
res = requests.get(url, params=params)
if res.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception("ERROR: API request unsuccessful.")
data = res.json()
mylist = data["stats"][0]["splits"]

toi = data["stats"][0]["splits"][0]["stat"]["timeOnIce"]

print(f"{mylist}")
print(f"{toi}")

inputDate = '2019-12-29'
for item in mylist:
    if inputDate == item['date']:
        idx = mylist.index(item)
        print ('Index: %s' %idx)
        print (item)

        # This will print all matched to date
        # If you want to stop after first find, uncomment below
        #break
```

Comment: Thank-you. I like that answer better then what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had came up with.

```
idx = 0
        while d != data["stats"][0]["splits"][c]["date"]:
            idx += 1
```